# Find 2D peak prominence using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, topography

I found this scipy function [scipy.signal.peak_prominences](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_prominences.html) that finds the [topographic prominence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_prominence) of specified local maxima in a 1d sequence.

But my application requires locating important peaks in a 2D array. I'm aware of some peak finding methods, such as doing a maximum filtering, which both scipy and skimage have their implementations. Also skimage's `h_maxima()` allows filtering local peaks that have a minimal relative height. But these only give the coordinates of the peaks, not their prominence .

So how do I compute peak prominence on a 2d array?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what's going on inside skimage's `h_maxima`, is it true that `h_maxima` gives peaks whose prominence >= h, so to get all prominence values I need to scan through the height with a small step?

Answer (score 8):

I've cooked a python module using enclosing contour method, following wiki's definition:

> The prominence of a peak is the height of the peak’s summit above the
>   lowest contour line encircling it but containing no higher summit
>   within it.

optionally one can filter out local peaks that have small cross section area or low prominence values.

I've put the code here: https://github.com/Xunius/python_peak_promience2d, if anyone finds any issue or possible improvement please fire an issue or PR.

A demo graph:
[image]